# Usando el enumerated como se almacena un valor que no sea el Ordinal ni el Name

Tags: java, jpa, enum

En JPA para el @Enumerated, como hago si quiero almacenar en la BD es un valor que no es el nombre ni el ordinal. Por ejemplo:

```
public enum EstadoVerificacion {
    NO_VERIFICADO( 10, "No verificado" ),
    VERIFICADO( 20, "Ya se verifico" ),
    DOCUMENTO_GENERADO( 35, "Documento generado" );

    private final int id;
    private final String description;

    private EstadoVerificacion( int id, String description ) {
        this.id = id;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
}
```

Quiero que sea el valor del campo id quien se almacene en la BD.

Otra pregunta, utilizar el Ordinal ¿no es muy riesgoso? es decir otro programador (en un entorno compartido) puede querer agregar un nuevo estado y no necesariamente meterlo al final, el enum lo permite. Puede que haya un pacto de caballeros de nunca cambiar el orden y agregarlo al final, pero dado que no es una restricción de java, cualquiera puede no conocerla y agregarlo donde mejor le plazca, afectando entonces el número que se venía almacenando en la BD. Yo por eso razón (y quiero saber si hay una mejor práctica) mejor los hago como el ejemplo que pasé y así obligo a que sea ese id y ningún otro, lo malo es que no puedo poner en los entities la enumeración sino tengo que poner un int o long, quitándole elegancia al método, que se viera mucho mejor si se restringe al enum.

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si estás usando JPA 2.1 tienes la posibilidad de usar un converter para especificar como convertir el enumerado.

Te dejo este [link](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-persisting-enums-in-jpa) con el ejemlo.

Sino, no iría por la opción del ordinal, sino que usaría el nombre del enumerado (@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)). Igualmente tienes el mismo problema, si alguien cambia el nombre se rompería el estado en la base de datos.

Ahora, si es necesario que tenga su id y vas a ir agregando mas en el futuro, quizás sea conveniente almacenarlo como una entidad mas en tu base de datos.